Manga with an elf main character who is an experienced fighter
Basically the main character is an elf and despite his advanced age, he's young looking. He's a very experienced fighter too. It has mature content and gives off berserk vibes in terms of the theme, not the plot lines.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  What/who does he fight?  What kind of mature content, and how does that fit the plot?

Not enough information. Is it Übel Blatt?
